# Why I cant use jQuery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have `jquery-2.1.3.js` library in the `/opt/lampp/htdocs` directory and to test it I included it in a html file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js">
            $("p").css("color","orange")
            $("body").css("background","#00ff00")
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

From this I expected to change all text within `</p>` tags to orange and set the `</body>` background to green but I all I get is simple output : `Some paragraph` in default color and default background. Why this dont work?

Comment: Perfectly understandable mistake, and it would have been perfectly reasonable for `script` elements to work that way. They don't, but it would have been reasonable for them to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

Use another script block for your jQuery script

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.js">
</script>
<script>
    $("p").css("color","orange")
    $("body").css("background","#00ff00")
</script>
```

Comment: @underscore: As long as an element is defined by HTML **above** the script tag containing code operating on it, the element is available to that code. It can even be *immediately* after it, but in practice it's usually better to put the scripts at the end, before the closing `</body>` tag.